# iPad Console Error Message Help

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Can anyone help me decipher what's causing my program to crash? I've got a 5 tab bar controller set up, when I load each tab bar, i'm loading a custom table cell with data from a plist file.

```
this is the error message output to console;
[Session started at 2011-04-28 12:53:05 +0100.]
2011-04-28 12:53:09.344 FiveTabView[62565:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "Drinks" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00db3be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f085c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00d6c628 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d6c59a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
    4   UIKit                               0x004c1324 -[UITableViewController loadView] + 275
    5   UIKit                               0x0036a5e3 -[UIViewController view] + 56
    6   UIKit                               0x0037d230 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 120
    7   UIKit                               0x0037bd86 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 64
    8   UIKit                               0x0037db7e -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 263
    9   UIKit                               0x0037d9ed -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 352
    10  UIKit                               0x002bca6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    11  UIKit                               0x004ba1f2 -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 422
    12  UIKit                               0x002bca6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    13  UIKit                               0x0034b1b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    14  UIKit                               0x0034d647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    15  UIKit                               0x0034b16c -[UIControl sendActionsForControlEvents:] + 49
    16  UIKit                               0x002bca6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    17  UIKit                               0x0034b1b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    18  UIKit                               0x0034d647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    19  UIKit                               0x0034c1f4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    20  UIKit                               0x002e10d1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    21  UIKit                               0x002c237a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    22  UIKit                               0x002c7732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x016e9a36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00d95064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf56f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf2983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf2240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf2161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x016e8268 GSEventRunModal + 217
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x016e832d GSEventRun + 115
    31  UIKit                               0x002cb42e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    32  FiveTabView                         0x00002420 main + 102
    33  FiveTabView                         0x000023b1 start + 53
    34  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling `setValue:forKey:` on an object that has been uninitialised (and the memory pointer is pointing elsewhere) or you are actually calling it on the wrong object?

Comment: Thanks, for that, I think I worked out the problem, i'd declared a load of stuff in the wrong place, but now i'm getting this error message (see above)

Comment: I sort of get what it's saying? That when I select the tab bar, it can't find the right page to load and therefore crashes out?